# Discord.js sudo command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a sudo command for my Discord bot. The way it's supposed to work is that I give it a user and a command to execute, and it uses `client.emit("message", sudoMessage)` to execute that command. sudoMessage would be a modified version of the message, where the member, author, and content are replaced. Then, it's handled by my bot as though it were a message sent by that user with that command.

The problem I ran into is that I can't simply replace the properties of `message`. Replacing `message.content` works fine, but trying to replace `message.member` throws an error like "Cannot set property which only has a getter".

So then I tried starting with my sudo command and filling it in with the data from message, like this:

```
if (message.content.startsWith("sudo") && message.author.id === "my id") {
        let hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

        let sudo = {
            content: command,
            author: mentioned.user,
            member: mentioned,
            guild: message.guild,
            url: message.url
        };

        for (var key in message) {
            if (!hasOwn.call(sudo, key)) {
                sudo[key] = message[key]
            }
        }

        client.emit("message", sudo)
    }
```

However, as you can see, I had to manually fill in guild and url, as those aspects of `message` (as well as many others) didn't get copied over--only some properties actually got applied to `sudo`. This method seems like it would require me to manually copy over a ton of properties from `message` over to `sudo`, which is not what I want to do. How can I build a `sudo` message object that has a special content, author, and member, while filling everything else in with data from the actual message automatically?

Comment: Consider moving your edit into an answer and accepting your answer. [Self-answering your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is encouraged because it allows users to find the solution to a question more easily, and also marks this question as solved so users who are trying to find questions to answer don't come across this one.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've figured it out. I just needed to do something like

```
Object.defineProperty(message, "member", {
            value: mentioned
        });
```

Hopefully somebody in the future can be helped by this.